# Is Famished Paladin and Resplendent Mentor a legal infinite life combo?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I know I couldn't use these in a Standard game but is it legal for a casual game?
If I control both [Resplendent Mentor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bResplendent%20Mentor%5d) and [Famished Paladin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFamished%20Paladin%5d) can I gain as much life as I want as long as no spells are cast that affect these two cards?

I know that combos that play off each other and have no end are not legal because the game can't continue, but does this combo work and is it valid?

Comment: "I know that combos that play off each other and have no end are not legal because the game can't continue" It's not clear what you mean by this; but it doesn't sound correct. There are plenty of combos that allow for an arbitrary large number of things to happen, and they are perfectly allowed within the rules.

Comment: @GendoIkari I believe that what they are getting at is that a loop that consists entirely of mandatory acts forces a draw. They're not "not legal" per se, but they do prevent a win.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that works. Congratulations for finding two cards that work so well together. It's not legal in Standard but it is in other formats (e.g. Modern). There are no rules for which cards are allowed in casual games, it's just what you agree on with your opponent(s).

Note that you can't gain *infinite* life, as stated in the title; you *can* gain as much life as you want. E.g. you can declare that you want to execute the loop (tapping the Paladin with the ability it gained from the Mentor) one million times, and you end up with one million extra life. If your opponent has an 'infinite' damage loop, they'll be able to execute theirs for a larger amount than one million and still kill you. They'd be advised to kill your creatures first, otherwise you can respond to their loop iteration with another activation of the Paladin's life-gaining ability.

Comment: Your last sentence is not correct. If a player has an "infinite" damage combo against the other player's Mentor/Paladin combo, that player also only has an "arbitrarily large but finite" amount of damage, to which the other player can respond with the same amount of life gain. If a player proposes a "1 million damage" shortcut, the other player can alway respond with a counter-proposal of "whenever you do a point of damage, I make a point of life".

Comment: In that case, a fragmented loop as per 720.3 would occur, and each player could only activate their respective combo once.

Comment: Thank you I have a white and black deck built around these two cards and Epicure of blood. It seems pretty powerful and as far as I can tell it is.                        Here is a link to Epicure of Blood. https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=447231